# React router not routing when wrapped

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-router

If you could point the error it will be grateful, I'm frazzled. I'm using react router as such:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={SplashScreen} />
         <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
      </div>
</Router>
```

This works perfectly fine. The moment however I wrap another component around the div, in this case a `StartupLogic` component, routing stops working
Specifically I'm using:

```
dispatch(push("/login"));
```

When `StartupLogic` is not wrapped around the div this works fine meaning the url bar changes to `localhost:3000/login` and the LoginComponent is mounted.

When the StartupLogic component IS mounted around the div, the url bar changes to `localhost:3000/login` but the `LoginComponent` doesnt render, I'm stuck there looking at the `SplashScreen`.

The StartupLogic component:

```
class AppDelegate extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getX().then(allCountries => {
      this.props.getY().then(res => {

        setTimeout(() => {

          console.log(this);
          debugger;
          this.forceUpdate();
        },5000)

      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: For conditional rendering I think you need to wrap the 2 Route inside a Switch. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Comment: Maybe your StartupLogic component has something that causes it to never rerender after the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Wrapping the Routes within a component like

```
<Router history={history}>
    <StartupLogic >
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={SplashScreen} />
         <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
      </div>
    <StartupLogic >
</Router>
```

you should move the Routes within the component directly  and get get the Route params using `withRouter` in the `WrappedRoute` like

```
const StartupLogic = () => {
   return (
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={SplashScreen} />
         <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
      </div>
   )
}

export default withRouter(StartupLogic);
```

and use it like

```
<Router history={history}>
    <StartupLogic />
</Router>
```

Comment: This would work and i understand the issue and why using withRouter is after finding and reading a post. However, the StartupLogic component also has a this.forceUpdate after a timeout set of 5 seconds after which all the actions have happened and it still wont rerender.